# Sort HTML row's cells

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to sort the `<td>`'s inside a `<tr>` based on the text content.

```
sortedCells = Array.from(tr.cells).sort((a,b) => b.textContent - a.textContent);
const cellsLength = tr.cells.length;
for(i = 0; i < cellsLength; i++) {
  const cell = tr.cells[i];
  tr.replaceChild(sortedCells[i], cell);
}
```

When this code is executed, it will shorten the `tr.cells` by one, so in one of the `replaceChild()` calls, something goes wrong, as a result, i will get a shorter `<tr>` i cant figure out why.

Comment: Looks like you are changing the structure of tr element, while iterating the children

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A node can only be in the DOM once. So by replacing a cell with another one, that is already in an other position, you are moving the cell to the new place.

E.G: You want to replace the cell on position 1 with the cell on position 7. Now cell 7 is on position 1, but its original position would be empty now. Therefore cell 8 is now on position 7, cell 9 on position 8...

So instead of replacing your existing cells, I would recommend to just empty the tr and fill it up again.

```
let sortedCells = Array.from(tr.cells).sort((a,b) => b.textContent - a.textContent);
tr.innerHTML = "";
for(let cell of sortedCells) {
  tr.appendChild(cell);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a little modification in the javascript which works fine for me. Try this and let me know if you any other issue

```
const tr = document.querySelector('tr'); 
const sortedCells = Array.from(tr.cells).sort((a, b) => {
  return b.textContent.localeCompare(a.textContent);
});

const cellsLength = tr.cells.length;
for (let i = cellsLength - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  const cell = tr.cells[i];
  tr.replaceChild(sortedCells[i], cell);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid iterating over tr.cells to avoid issues when replacing child nodes, instead use sortedCells.

```
const tr = document.querySelector('tr');
const sortedCells = Array.from(tr.cells).sort((a, b) => {
    const textA = parseFloat(a.textContent);
    const textB = parseFloat(b.textContent);
    return textB - textA;
});
const cellsLength = sortedCells.length; // Use sortedCells.length here
for (let i = 0; i < cellsLength; i++) {
    const cell = sortedCells[i]; // Iterate over sortedCells
    tr.replaceChild(cell, tr.cells[i]);
}
```